# Развертывание на весь экран блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Приветствую.

На сайте https://webgradients.com/ если кликнуть по любому из градиентов - он развернется на весь экран с анимацией. Как сделать подобный эффект для блока?

Заметил, что при клике в body добавляется класс state-fixed к уже существующему state-show, но разобраться с js-кодом, когда он еще и сжат, мне сложно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Класс тут задается просто что бы скролл убрать. Делаете невидимый блок, при клике на градиент ставите его в то место куда кликнули, задаете нужный градиент (узнав его у элемента по которому кликнули), увеличиваете до размеров экрана .... Вроде тут и в js особо лезть не надо, что бы это понять. Что уже пробовали? Какие проблемы возникли?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
var ripple = $('.ripple'), // "капля"
  rippleSize = screenProp(), // размер капли
  posLeft = 0,
  posTop = 0;

ripple.outerWidth(rippleSize * 2).outerHeight(rippleSize * 2); // задаем капле размер в 2 раза больше размера экрана, чтобы "покрыть" всю видимую область страницы

$('.gradient').click(function(e) { // клик на градиент
  $('body').addClass('fixed'); // блокируем прокрутку экрана
  posLeft = e.pageX - rippleSize - $(window).scrollLeft(); // положение капли слева
  posTop = e.pageY - rippleSize - $(window).scrollTop(); // положение капли сверху
  var gradient = $(this).attr('data-gradient-css'); // получаем код градиента
  ripple.addClass('ripple--active').css({ // добавляем класс для увеличения и прописываем стили
    'left': posLeft + 'px',
    'top': posTop + 'px',
    'background-image': gradient
  });
  setTimeout(function() { // после увеличения
    ripple.addClass('ripple--complete'); // добавляем класс, который выровнит каплю точно по краям экрана
  }, 500); // время анимации увеличения
});

ripple.on('click', function() { // при клике на каплю
  if (ripple.hasClass('ripple--complete')) { // если анимация закончилась
    $('body').removeClass('fixed'); // возвращаем странице прокрутку
    ripple.removeClass('ripple--complete ripple--active'); // удаляем классы
  }
});

$(window).on('resize', function() { // при ресайзе окна
  rippleSize = screenProp(); // пересчитываем размер капли
  ripple.outerWidth(rippleSize * 2).outerHeight(rippleSize * 2); // и задаем ей полученные значения
});

// функция для определения максимального значения из высоты и ширины экрана
function screenProp() {
  if ($(window).width() > $(window).height()) {
    return $(window).width();
  } else {
    return $(window).height();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body.fixed {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: url(https://i.imgur.com/wz8iY4B.png) 16 16, pointer;
}

.ripple {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: url(https://i.imgur.com/NRHTafk.png) 16 16, crosshair;
}

.ripple--active {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.ripple--complete {
  left: 0!important;
  top: 0!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
  border-radius: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fad0c4 0%, #ffd1ff 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(to top, #fad0c4 0%, #ffd1ff 100%)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffecd2 0%, #fcb69f 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(to right, #ffecd2 0%, #fcb69f 100%)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(132, 250, 176) 0%, rgb(143, 211, 244) 100%);" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(132, 250, 176) 0%, rgb(143, 211, 244) 100%)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ripple"></div>
```

Comment: Cheg, подскажи, а что-бы менять иконку курсора, можно использовать только SVG или можно иконки другого формата тоже вставлять? читал описание, вроде там расширение  иконки "cur".. не могу справиться с ситуацией

Comment: @Air для современных браузеров можно и .png. .cur - для ie

Comment: Не хочу хвастаться, но с первой минуты, когда узнал что такое css, у меня по нем не  возникало вопросов, он для меня проще пареной репы, а вот единственное с чем не справился....  а размер иконки имеет значение? ну не получается, не видит он у меня картинку, pointer показывает

Comment: @Air думаю, для этого стоит отдельный вопрос опубликовать

Comment: Cheg, глянь, вопрос опубликован.